# 2 Adobe Native Extentions conflict in Android project

Tags: android, flash-builder, adobe-native-extensions

I have to use 2 ANEs in my android project.
When I attach 2nd ANE Flash Builder shows a lot of such problems:

```
Error occurred while packaging the application:
aapt tool failed:C:\Users\***\res\layout\anesample.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/cnn').
```

All of them are with `@string` problem.

All strings are present and in the `res\values\strings.xml`.

Both ANEs work well in another project but I could not find a difference between this projects.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANEs work fine together fhen I recompiled one of them with different name of `strings.xml`, i.e. `srings-fb.xml`.

But you can imagine situation when every ANE library is compiled not by yourself…

Comment: can't you just simply rename it inside the ANE?

Comment: Yes. ANE is a zip in fact.